# Pass username and password as Variables

Tags: karate

I am looking to use variables instead of hard code UID and Password in .feature files

```
Background:
        * def xmlPayload = read('request.xml')
        * def UserID = UID
        * def Password = PWD
        * def Token = Token
        * url MppBaseUrl

@XYZ
  Scenario: create user details main 

    Given path '/customer/v1/'
    And request xmlPayload
    When method PUT
    Then status 201
    * print response
    And def userResponse = response
    * def Cust_ID =  $userResponse/entry[1]/title[1]
    * print Cust_ID
    Given path '/customer/v1/',Cust_ID + '/'
    * header Authorization = call read('basic-auth.js') { username:'ADMIN' , password:'Pa11word'}
```

The above works good, however the password is getting printed in the final HTML reports. I want to avoid this by passing a variable instead something like below which do not work of course

```
* header Authorization = call read('basic-auth.js') { username:UserID , password:Password}
```

My syntax might be having a problem. Can anyone please help in correcting my syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the docs for log masking: https://github.com/intuit/karate#log-masking

```
karate.configure('logModifier', new LM());
```

Comment: Thanks Peter I found it :) Also I was passing parameter wrongly , Below works for me                                          * header Authorization = call read('basic-auth.js') { username: '#(Cust_ID3)', password: 'WelcomeABC' }